# Powershell in C# Get-Credential UI

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm writing an installer wrapper for a Windows C# Service. The installer is written in C# but needs to execute Powershell commands. As part of the installation I need to either get the current user's credentials, or have the user provide credentials. I need to use a PowerShell for the service installation (using `New-Service`), but I need to provide the credentials as a `PSCredential` object.

Such an object can be returned by `Get-Credentials`, but I can't invoke this command without accessing the PS Host UI, which I don't seem to be able to do.

I can do this the lazy way, and throw up a custom dialog asking for a username and password, and cram those in to a new `PSCredential`, but that is very bad practice.

I can also get these credentials by PInvoking my way through `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials`, but again, this is extremely kludgy and eventually results in a plain text password in memory which I'd like to avoid.

Surely there is some intermediate? I'm running this interaction from a WPF form, so I can happily present the user with a credentials dialog, but I don't know how to do this in a sensible way.

It would also be nice if there was a secure way to create a service and pass through the currently logged in user as the "run as" user.

Simply put, I want to create a Windows service that runs as a specified user. How do I do this programmatically in C#?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear of what you want to do.

Are you using powershell inside c# code or powershell only, to install the c# code?

Are you searching for a solution in powershell or c#?

Are you asking for a solution on password security or on secure service creation?

This (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=net-7.0) c# class: "Represents text that should be kept confidential, such as by deleting it from computer memory when no longer needed. This class cannot be inherited."

I would use this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertto-securestring?view=powershell-7.3) for powershell.

Comment: I'm writing an installer in C# that executes the PowerShell `New-Service` command. As I said in the question, I can build the required `PSCredential` object manually, but this is bad practice. The link you provided to `SecureString` states that it should not be used for new development work.

Comment: Put simply, I have a C# application. I want to pop up a standard windows request for credentials, and use those credentials as parameters in creating a new service. Alternatively, I want to create that service with the runas user set to the currently logged on users credentials. I'd like to do this in a way that follows good security practice if possible.

Comment: @AndyWynn It doesn't say that you shouldn't per se, it says that they dont recommend using it. As it states "The general approach of dealing with credentials is to avoid them and instead rely on other means to authenticate, such as certificates or Windows authentication." In your case, this would maybe be the best solution, or the closest you will get to what you are asking.

Comment: @AndyWynn SecureString is not an OS concept, but as stated "It just makes the window getting the plain text shorter; it doesn't fully prevent it as .NET still has to convert the string to a plain text representation." so you would be able to avoid this.